# How to make a line align in the middle after i <br/> it

Tags: html, css

For example - `<h1>Welcome to the best blog website!<br/> New blog is out!<h1>`

Shows like this -

```
Welcome to the best blog website!

New blog is out!
```

I want it to show like this -

```
Welcome to the best blog website!

        New blog is out!
```

Comment: The simplest method is to use correct HTML structure. This should not use a `br` at all. This should be two **separate elements**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the element to be `inline-block` then center the text inside:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to the best blog website!<br/> New blog is out!</h1>
```

If you want to keep the block level behavior you can add an extra div:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to the best blog website!<br/> New blog is out!</h1>
</div>
<p>some text</p>
```

Or use `display:table`

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to the best blog website!<br/> New blog is out!</h1>
<p>some text</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<blockquote>New blog is out!</blockquote>
```

If you want same text as code. Then add tag like this.

```
<pre> <blockquote>New blog is out!</blockquote></pre>
```

Comment: May I ask - why use `blockquote`?

Comment: blockquote is a tag which gives indentation. It gives indentation of 4 space which is universally defined. In some languages like Python there are mandatory indentation.  So it works as indented text. I know you dont require Python here but just for information.

Comment: As per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/blockquote), a blockquote is _used to represent a **quoted** section from another source_, which is not the case here. IMO, it should not be used only for stylistic reasons, as HTML focuses on the semantics, CSS takes care of styling. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<blockquote>Text</blockquote>
Text
</body>
</html>

Run this in html file. You will get the difference.

Comment: Yeah, it adds some indentation, but a) @Helenesh is correct, it is the wrong HTML Element in this case and b) this does not actually center the text at all. Try `<body> <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and so on ... </blockquote> Text </body>` this in your HTML file. You will get the difference.